# Data from multiple lists using single REST API call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest

I need to get some data based on a key field from multiple lists. For this, I may need to do multiple API calls. Is there any way to avoid this ? To get all the data from multiple lists in a single API call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize SharePoint REST search API for that purpose, in particular to specify managed property in search query to return list items that contains value for that column.

### Example

Assume we have site column named `WorkspaceType`. Since SharePoint 2013 automatically creates managed property for site columns (you could follow [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/03/06/from-site-column-to-managed-property-what-s-up-with-that.aspx) great article for a details) ,then we could construct the following search query to return items that contains value `Team`:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='WorkspaceTypeOWSCHCS:Team'
```

where `WorkspaceTypeOWSCHCS` is the name of managed property.

Comment: Will it work with multi lookup columns ?

Comment: Sure, I've tested it with a multi lookup column.

Comment: How can we create a managed property with type as 'Multi Lookup' ? I can find the 'Text' and 'Y/N' types there. I have tried with the 'Text' type, but I'm not getting the results.

Comment: It's treated the same as text type.